# Sound editor for Mac to manually mix (crossfade) music files?

Tags: osx, music-production, audio-editing, macos

I have a long music mp3 file and want to cut out a part in the middle. I would like to create a smooth transition between the end of the first and the start of the second part, like a crossfade, and time it pricesely to keep both parts in sync.

I know how to do this from the command line with ffmpeg. But is there also a visual tool for macOs to do this manually, for more conveniently / visually timing the exact crossfade position?

Back in the old days I have used SoundForge on Windows. Is there something like that for macOs, preferably open source?

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/):

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform, Windows, Linux & Mac OS-X.
- Multi-track
- Supports most sound file formats
- Adjust volume with Compressor, Amplify, Normalize, Fade In/Out, Studio Fade Out, Crossfade Clips, **Crossfade Tracks** and Adjustable Fade effects.

Personally I find it fills every audio editing task that I have ever needed.

[image: Official Screenshot]